# function in C returns always the same arbitrary number

Tags: c, function, variables

So i´m trying to get the power of any two numbers,

```
int expo(int base, int expon){
    int z = 1;
    printf("%i",&z);  // Here i get 635678
    if (expon == 0){
        printf("A");  // this gets printed if expon== 0
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        for (int x=0; x < expon; x++){ 
            z *= base;
            printf("%i",&z); // here i get 6356780
        }
        return z;
    }

}
```

The thing that amazes me the most is the first 635678, i just told the computer that z = 1 !, the second one is that when it prints A, it doesnt even return 1. It always return 6356776. ( i just declare an int value as being the result of the function and print the int, maybe i even do that bad). I dont care about this particular function, i just want to know what i am telling to the computer, because it is obviously not what i think. 
Thanks and sorry because there is a good chance that this question should not be here.

Comment: You are printing references (ie: memory Addresses), not the variable

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're doing it wrong like this:

```
printf("%i",&z);
```

`%i` is for printing an integer, but what you pass is a *pointer to an integer* -- you apply the `&` (address of) operator.

This is undefined behavior. Simple solution: remove the `&`.

---

I have a theory how you got to this code: you were probably taught to use `scanf()` for reading input (another thing I [would question](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html), but let's put this aside for now).

With `scanf()`, you need to pass a *pointer to an `int`* with the `%i` conversion specifier. But that's because `scanf()` has to set the value of a variable, and as in C, variables are *passed by value*, this is only possible through a pointer.

`printf()` on the other hand only needs a value to print, it doesn't have to modify anything. So it directly expects this value, not a pointer to it.

Comment: You're correct about the OP's error, but don't confuse him by calling this "undefined behavior". It's perfectly well-defined: he's printing the integer value of the address of z, exactly as he asked it to.

Comment: well, what it prints is strictly *undefined*, because a pointer is not a compatible type to an integer ... but what likely happens is that it prints the *location* (or, at least, the significant bits of it that fit into an `int`) of your variable. Will probably look quite "random".

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker it's undefined, a pointer doesn't necessarily fit into an `int`. The only *defined* way of printing a pointer is using `%p` **and** casting it to `void *`.

Comment: Yes, but it is nonetheless well-defined behavior. If the program segfaulted, for example, or printed different values for the same address, you would be rightly angry that your compiler is broken.

Comment: True, a pointer might not fit into an int. But the compiler is *required* to fit as many bits in as will fit, in a consistent way, and print that result. It is not allowed to do anything else. "Undefined behavior" is a term from the standard with a specific meaning. It doesn't just mean "looks unpredictable to a human".

Comment: C11, §7.21.6.1, number 9: "*If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.*" -- any more questions? It's **undefined**, by the very words of the standard.

Comment: Interesting. That's not how I remember it, but I'll accept your quote at face value. Personally I'd still consider the compiler broken if it segfaulted here.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker "segfault" is not a term of the standard, and UB by no means guarantees a crash.... It just says you can't possibly know what will happen.

Comment: UB means the compiler is allowed to do anything--fail, succeed, catch fire, nasal demons, etc. And I would appreciate a compiler that gives me a warning or error here. But I would certainly not appreciate a compiler that chose to not compile this or to do anything other than the obvious conversions. Just my point of view from having grown up with old-fashioned C, I guess.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker `printf("%i",&z);` is undefined behavior  - it is not well-defined behavior.  The size of an `int` and the size of an `int*` are not necessarily the same nor does code need to pass these types of variables using the same mechanism.  Certainly many compilers gives warnings about such basic problems yet OP reports no message.  A difference from older compilers to now is that compilers are more likely than ever to do strange things with UB as there are optimizing - assuming correct coding.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker about the *old-fashioned* C, I don't know much about *K&R*, but at least for standard C, it was already undefined [back in C89](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.9.6.1). Passing a pointer for `%d` just happens to work on the most common platforms, and if `int` is the same size (as it is on 32bit x86), it even gives the "expected" result. That's the worst thing about UB, it can *hide* quite well... Remember what happened with a lot of code when first compiled for `x86_64` -- loads of UB discovered ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the location in memory of your variable z not the value z contains. if you put & in front of the variable you get the address in memory, just put printf("%i", z), to get his value.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%i",&z);
```

Here, you're printing the address of z and not its value. What you want is instead:

```
int expo(int base, int expon){
int z = 1;
printf("%d",z);
if (expon == 0){
    printf("A");  // this gets printed if expon== 0
    return 1;
}
else{
    for (int x=0; x < expon; x++){ 
        z *= base;
        printf("%d",z);
    }
    return z;
  }
}
```

Just drop the & reference operator in front of z.